# Doubt on derivation of OLS estimators as unbiased estimators of Optimal Linear Predictors

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear, unbiased-estimator

I'm studying from C. Shalizi's lecture notes https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/ .

In the third chapter he introduces the optimal linear estimator of a random variable $Y$ conditioned to another (possibly vector) $X$: $$f(X)=\beta X,\qquad \beta = \frac{1}{\text {Cov}(X,X)}\text {Cov}(X,Y).$$

Defining the error $Y-f(X)=\epsilon$ he states that, in general, $\mathbb E(\epsilon|X)\neq 0$, which I understand.

However, at page 45 he is proving that the Ordinary Least Squares estimators $\hat \beta$ give unbiased estimates of $\beta $ (as far as I understand, without any assumption about the actual correctness of the linear model). Here's the derivation.

---

[image]

---

My confusion concerns the step from Eq. (2.24) to (2.25), i.e. the second $+0$. Isn't he assuming here that the *conditional* expectation is $\mathbb E (\epsilon \vert X)=0$? And, relatedly, why in Eq. (2.24) has the $\mathbb E(|\boldsymbol X = \boldsymbol x)$ for $\mathbb \epsilon$ been replaced by an apparently unconditional expectation mean?

---

After some thought I realized this is probably just an error/typo from the author, which really meant that the *unconditional* expectation (averaged over the data set $\boldsymbol X=\boldsymbol x$) of the $\hat \beta$ estimator is equal to $\beta$. Indeed, it doesn't make much sense to think of being able to estimate the full regression line by making repeated measurements of $Y$ for few fixed values of $X$... unless the truth is a linear model, for sure :-)

If nobody comes up with corrections or anything to add, I will add the above as answer.

Comment: yes. what you say is correct. formally, it seems that the author is using what is referred to as the tower property:  $E(E(\epsilon | X = x)) = E(\epsilon) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what is being proven, this is just an error/typo from the author.

The linear coefficient estimator(s) $\hat \beta$ is *conditionally* (over the input data) unbiased only if the underlying process is truly linear.

On the other hand, $\hat \beta$ is an *unconditionally* unbiased estimator of the optimal linear predictor. This can be formally proved by integrating Eq. (2.24) over the marginal $X$ distribution and using the tower property as pointed out by @mlofton.